# How to dynamically change Flow embedded inside LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow

I am trying to reload a flow inside LWC based on Flow Name. This Flow name i Pass using a button click on LWC dynamically. I am using lightning-flow to show the flows.

On button click I just change the flow api name but it doesn't work and the initial flow is always shown. I think it is because of the documentation which says "This attribute doesn't set if there's an ongoing interview for this flow. Pause or finish the interview in progress to start a new one."

Can someone help me in understanding how can I achieve this so I can dynamically change Flow shown within LWC?

I think somehow from LWC i need to finish the flow-interview-id, but not sure how to do that, or maybe relaod the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just changing the `flow-api-name` attribute will not change the flow, you need to completely rerender the `lightning-flow` component.

Here is the code snippet that I had written for my blog post: [Call Lightning Screen Flow inside Lwc Component](https://www.forcetrails.com/2022/09/call-lightning-screen-flow-inside-lwc.html)
, last year. You can find the full code in this git repo: [call-flow-in-lwc](https://github.com/rahulgawale/call-flow-in-lwc/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/flowInLwc)

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card
        variant="Narrow"
        title="Flow in Lwc"
        icon-name="standard:account"
    >
        <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">

            <!-- Dynamically select the flow to run -->
            <lightning-combobox
                name="objectType"
                label="Select Object To Run Flow"
                value={flowApiName}
                placeholder="Select Object"
                options={options}
                onchange={handleChangeFlow}
            ></lightning-combobox>

            <!-- Invoke a Screen flow in LWC -->
            <lightning-flow
                if:true={showFlow}
                flow-api-name={flowApiName}
                flow-input-variables={flowInputVariables}
                onstatuschange={handleFlowStatusChange}
            >
            </lightning-flow>
        </div>
        <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
    </lightning-card>

</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
const timeout = 10;
export default class FlowInLwc extends LightningElement {
    flowApiName = "Create_Lead_Flow";
    showFlow = true;

    // Setting flow input variables,
    // hard coded only for demo purpose
    get flowInputVariables() {
        if (this.flowApiName === "Create_Lead_Flow") {
            return [
                {
                    name: "companyName",
                    type: "String",
                    value: "Burlington Textiles Corp of America"
                }
            ];
        }

        // Create_Contact_Flow
        return [
            {
                name: "accountId",
                type: "String",
                value: "001B000001QzX1wIAF"
            }
        ];
    }

    options = [
        { label: "Create Contact", value: "Create_Contact_Flow" },
        { label: "Create Lead", value: "Create_Lead_Flow" }
    ];

    handleChangeFlow(event) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.showFlow = false;
        this.flowApiName = event.target.value;

        // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.showFlow = true;
        }, timeout);
    }

    handleFlowStatusChange(event) {
        console.log("flow status", event.detail.status);
        if (event.detail.status === "FINISHED") {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Success",
                    message: "Flow Finished Successfully",
                    variant: "success"
                })
            );
        }
    }
}
```

FURTHER EXPLANATION -
So when we use if:true with a false value it removes the component from the browser window and vice-versa. But any such changes to the linked attributes are consolidated in a single event. so if you hide/show the component multiple times in the same function that will only take effect based on the last assigned value only and ignore any intermittent changes because the component is rendered after the event handler execution is finished.
So if the event handler changes the value from true to false and then true, lwc-engine would not notice that change that is why I created a delay and a new transaction apparently. I hope that helps. you can observe that inside a browser if done with the inspector on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul, this works like a charm. Can you also help me understand how this could work? does adding if:true actually reloads/Rerender the whole lightning-flow component? Do you think using this approach in general we can reload any html component in general ?
Also, this dint work if i remove the timeout, any reason why is that needed? Sorry just trying to understand the basics here

Comment: So when we use `if:true` with a false value it removes the component from the browser window and vice-versa. But any such changes to the linked attributes are consolidated in a single event. so if you hide/show the component multiple times in the same function that will only take effect based on the last assigned value only and ignore any intermittent changes because the component is rendered after the event handler execution is finished.

Comment: So if the event handler changes the value from true to false and then true, lwc-engine would not notice that change that is why I created a delay and a new transaction apparently. I hope that helps. you can observe that inside a browser if done with the inspector on. By the way please mark the answer as accepted if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense now. Very helpful

Comment: The above comments should be put in the answer since they are very important to the explanation of the solution. Once done, I'll upvote.

Comment: @PhilW comments are there now.